# MySQL connection doesn't work anymore

Tags: mysql, port, connection

I had two MySQL servers running (127.0.0.1:3306 and 127.0.0.1:3307). Now I get this strange error:
`mysql_connect(): Lost connection to MySQL server at 'reading initial communication packet'`
I can connect with localhost:3307, but there aren't any tables/databases. I'm sure `/etc/my.cnf` is right:

```
[mysqld_multi]
mysqld     = /usr/bin/mysqld_safe
mysqladmin = /usr/bin/mysqladmin
user       = root
password   = ***

[mysqld]
port       = 3306
socket   = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld2]
port       = 3307
socket   = /var/run/mysql/mysql2.sock
```

What can I do now? How can I restart the MySQL server? How can I make sure all tables still exists?

Comment: which System Error code do you get?

Comment: This one: 111. I did a mysqld_multi restart, that worked, but I couldn't find my own tables :(. Where are they?

Comment: I'm getting a headache, when I try the following in SSH, I get an error that it doesn't work, but it does in PHP???
root@vps8202:~# mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -p 3307 -u root
Enter password:
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '127.0.0.1'

Comment: -p is for password -P is for port.  Try mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -p -P 3307

Comment: Thanx, when I do SHOW DATABASES, it doesn't show the ones I created. (just mysql, phpmyadmin, information_schema and test). Where are my (old) databases? How can I find them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't specify the datadir for each of your mysqld instances.  E.g.:

```
[mysqld]
port = 3306
socket = /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock
datadir = /var/lib/mysql
```

Your question is a few months old, I sure hope you figured it out.